# Is it possible to execute a python file on a button click in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, button

My App.js file

```
return (
    <div>
      <button action={onClickHandler}>Click Me </button> 
    </div>
  );
```

My Test.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/data',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_link():
  print("I got Clicked")
  return {'name': "geek", "password": "This is PWD"}
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

On Button click the React App should execute the python file which will create an API and using fetch("url") in React i want to get that data.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you want to run python script on users computer?

Comment: yes , both the React file and the python file are on the users computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a script (or any program) on the users computer is strictly prohibited by browser security rules. Otherwise, some very bad scenarios were possible, like a script downloading a malware/trojan/virus/... file silently in the background and running it on the victim's machine. The user would not notice anything in the first line. The only thing an attacker would need to make them do is open a specific web site prepared like this (and there are many possibilities to achieve this).

Anyway, the script you posted looks like a server-side script (as Flask is a server-side framework), there is no need to download it on the client side to execute it. As the script says, the user would have to access `/data` on the server via a GET or POST request and, in return, get the JSON object containing `name` and `password` (please see notes below about that!).

I'd suggest you to store your script on a server (there are many ways to achieve this, one of them is described [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/deploy/)) and make your `onClickHandler` just send a GET or POST to it. (Let's say, your server is `myserver.com`, you would have to access `myserver.com/data` in your script.) Of course, during development, you can try it on `localhost` without the need for a production server setup.

Most important: I don't know your use case or what you want to achieve, but transferring user credentials that way is **absolutely insecure and dangerous**! Of course, for a playground or development environment, this is OK, but you should never use it in production as anyone able to access your `/data` endpoint will get to know your user name and password and be able to (mis)use it in the future!